# javascript conflict when using code 3 times

Tags: javascript

How do i get this code to work 3 times, one for my desktop version, one for my tablet and one for my desktop version. I want it to exit the menu when clicking on the window/document. Keep in mind that iam new in javascript... The code only seem to work one time. See my not complete webpage, www.adamlee.se

```
    <script>
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function desktopmyFunction() {
document.getElementById("desktopmyDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick2 = function(event) {
if (!event.target.matches('.desktop-dropbtn')) {

var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("desktop-dropdown-content");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
  var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
  if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
  }
}
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: There is no valid event property called `window.onclick2`.

Comment: `onclick2` is not an event listener property, did you mistype `onclick`?

Comment: Its a miss, theres should not be a 2 after onclick.

Comment: Byt its still Sony work...